# How to get total price of clicked items using data attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, math, custom-data-attribute

I made a script, which grabs information from data attributes and displays it on click. Everything works fine, except a total price function. I am not able to do this.

A part of JS:

```
var informacija = $(".informacija");

$( ".item").each(function() {

   var fotke = $(this).data("fotke");
   var pavadinimas = $(this).data("pavadinimas");
   var kaina = $(this).data("kaina");

   $(this).find("button").click(function(){ 

     $('.noitems').hide();
     $('.totalitems').show();

     informacija.append("<div class='perka'><div class='fotke' style='...some styles... background-image: url("+ fotke + ");'></div><div class='tekstas'><h1>"+ pavadinimas +"</h1><h1>£<b class='price'>"+ kaina +"</b></h1></div><div class='nereik'>da</div></div>");

    var viso = $(".perka").length;
    $(".viso").append("<span>"+ viso +"</span>");
    // $(this).unbind('click');
    var total = 0;
    total += parseInt(kaina);
    $('.totalprice').append(total);

    // ... etc
```

**My question:**

At the moment i am able to display everything, except total clicked items price. I dont know how to do that.

Here is full demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3y24vmp/)

Thanks for any help, and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare `total` as global variable and use `html()` instead of `append()` to set total price.

```
var informacija = $(".informacija");
var total = 0;

$(".item").each(function () {

    var fotke = $(this).data("fotke");
    var pavadinimas = $(this).data("pavadinimas");
    var kaina = $(this).data("kaina");

    $(this).find("button").click(function () {
        $('.noitems').hide();
        $('.totalitems').show();
        informacija.append("<div class='perka'><div class='fotke' style='background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:50% 50%; background-image: url(" + fotke + ");'></div><div class='tekstas'><h1>" + pavadinimas + "</h1><h1>£<b class='price'>" + kaina + "</b></h1></div><div class='nereik'>da</div></div>");
        var viso = $(".perka").length;
        $(".viso").append("<span>" + viso + "</span>");
        // $(this).unbind('click');

        total += parseInt(kaina);

        $('.totalprice').html(total);

        $(".perka").each(function () {
            $(this).find(".nereik").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                var viso = $(".perka").length;
                $(".viso").append("<span>" + viso + "</span>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/t3y24vmp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `total` variable outside of the `.each`, and don't use append, just use `$('.totalprice').text(total);`

```
var total = 0;

$(".item").each(function() {
    ...
    $('.totalprice').text(total);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0aw62fz9/)